# Ubuntu asks for Wifi password during startup even though it remembers it

Tags: 14.04, wireless

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and I have a problem with my wifi. Its not really a big deal, but its annoying. I got asked for my wifi login credentials during each startup even though Ubuntu remembers my username login and password.

This happens even before I login into the system. And it does not even matter wheter I enter the wifi password of not. If I just click "cancel" on that dialog and then login to the system, its going to connect to the wifi anyway (automatically). I am just trying to get rid og the dialog.

Any tips?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Network Manager saves the passwords in your keyring, which doesn't get unlocked until you login. You can stop it from connecting before you login by unchecking "Available to other users" in the connection settings.

Alternatively, you can tell it to store the password unencrypted by opting for "Store the password for all users" in the password field of the Security tab of the network's configuration details:

[image]

Comment: Apparently called `All users may connect to this network` in Ubuntu 2015.10

Comment: This is bad by design, either the password should be stored unencrypted or Network manager should disable this option at all. What sense makes this option then?

Comment: @Thomas you can tell it to store it unencrypted: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ug2Fs.png. I assume this option makes sense in the context of hidden networks, where you add the SSID once for all users but whoever wants to connect needs to have access to the password too.

Comment: @muru Thank you for this tip. How bad is this? Never noticed this. This belongs to the same option as the global switch option. I begin to feel like a hip Apple user searching for hidden feature unlocking. But we have easter anyway.

Comment: Maybe you can enhance your answer with this.

Answer (score 1):

Two solutions (**both tested only on Ubuntu 14.10!**):

1. Unchecking "Available to other users" in the connection settings (go to "Edit connections" in Network Manager menu). 
    **Slight problem (at least on Ubuntu 14.10)**: for some reason, the connection does not connect automatically, when you log in. I have to do it manually, even though the "Automatically connect to this network when it is available" box is checked.
2. ```
   cd /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/
   sudo nano <your_connection_name>
   ```

   Then find the section `[802-1x]`. Set the field `password-flags=0`. That's it. If you now reconnect to your wireless connection and check this connection file again you will see that a `password-flags` field was replaced by `password=<your_password>`. The password is in plain text, but the file is readable only by root, so it should not be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure it this also works on 14.04, but 15.10 has options in front of the wireless password field (accessed by clicking the small HDD icon) where you can choose if you want to store the password just for yourself or for every user. If you store the password for every user, it should automatically connect to the network.

Answer (score 0):

I just did the following changes:

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

And changed:

```
blacklist rtl8192cu
```

to

```
blacklist rtl8192c_common
```

`rtl8192cu` and `rtl8192c_common` conflicted each other, so I added them to the blacklist.

Fİnally shutdown my computer, and when I start up problem solved.

Comment: can you explain how this relates to the question please? Also, could you avoid recommending the use of `sudo` with graphical applications? use `sudo -i` and then `gedit /some/file` for example

Comment: @Zanna Can you explain why , for example, `sudo gedit somefile` is bad practice but `sudo -i` followed by `gedit somefile` is not? the second seems more dangerous to me.

Comment: @bracco23 see [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/270006/why-should-users-never-use-normal-sudo-to-start-graphical-applications)